# wpa_supplicant переподключение

Tags: linux, debian, сеть

Здравствуйте!

Прошу прощения если попал не в те метки, но тем не менее...

---

Ситация такая:

1. Debian Jessie (8)
2. Окружение cinnamon
3. Ноутбук Lenovo-v580c (драйвер сетевой карты broadcom 43421)
4. Wi-fi подключаю только из консоли (sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c ~/wpa.conf)

Проблема: При разрыве связи суппликант не поднимает соединение (не восстанавливает его). Т.е. если я на минуту отключаю роутер wifi - все, сети мне не видать до полной перезагрузки ноутбука.

При использовании Network manager - сеть вне зоны доступа (??? и это в 1-2х метрах от роутера ???)

При использовании wicd - не подходит пароль (перепробовал все методы шифрования, но никак...)

---

на первых порах выкладываю такие логи
логи wpa_supplicant при попытке переподключения:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 completed [id=0 id_str=]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="garmayev" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="garmayev" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="garmayev"
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="garmayev" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=3 locally_generated=1
nl80211: Was expecting local disconnect but got another disconnect event first
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="garmayev"
wlan0: Trying to associate with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 (SSID='garmayev' freq=2432 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c4:a8:1d:dc:c4:64 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="garmayev" auth_failures=3 duration=46 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

Comment: "сети мне не видать до полной перезагрузки ноутбука" - а перезапуск wpa_supplicant не помогает?

Comment: пробовал убиивать процесс wpa_supplicant, но не смог его запустить ::EPIC_FAIL:: ::FACE_PALM::
пробовал делать перезапуск сети - безрезультатно...